# Set one primary key value equal to another in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MYSQL with two columns:

- Company_Id (primary key auto_increment)
- Company_Name (unique key, varchar)

The resulting table might look like this:

- 1, Company A, LLC
- 2, Company B, LLC

There are a number of other tables in the database that reference Company_Id.

If a user edits the company name for row 2 and changes "Company B" to "Company A", I want to collapse the two rows in the table.

In other words, the row "2, Company B, LLC" would collapse into "1, Company A, LLC" and all references to Company_Id=2 would then reference Company_Id=1 instead.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: *Is there a way to do this?* No in single query. Yes in stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks Akina.  How would I use a stored procedure to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE update_company (company_id INT, new_name TEXT)
BEGIN
DECLARE duplicate INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062
  SET duplicate = TRUE;
UPDATE company_table   -- try to update 
  SET company_table.company_name = new_name
  WHERE company_table.company_id = company_id;
IF duplicate THEN      -- if duplicated name detected
    BEGIN
        UPDATE relative_table      -- update relative rows, join rows to existent row
          CROSS JOIN company_table
          SET relative_table.company_id = company_table.company_id
          WHERE relative_table.company_id = company_id 
            AND company_table.company_name = new_name;
        DELETE         -- remove the row to be edited
          FROM company_table
          WHERE company_table.company_id = company_id;
    END;
END IF;
END
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c5952addcab192a9564a220c51e1138)

Comment: This is certainly very helpful.  It is going to take a while to understand this.  I will accept the answer once I have played with this solution a bit more.

Comment: @NeilAggarwal If something is not clear-ask, do not hesitate.